# Flutter Firebase perform async operations on streambuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am a beginner in flutter and I am trying to check the type of user that log in into my application. I store the different user types and I want to retrieve this information when they log in. Right now when I print the user type it always return null. I guess I have to use async here but I am not sure what to do. What are the possible solutions to achieve this?

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static Future<FirebaseApp> initializeFirebase() async {
    FirebaseApp firebaseApp = await Firebase.initializeApp();
    return firebaseApp;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: initializeFirebase(),
      builder: (context, appSnapshot) {
        if (appSnapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Something went wrong');
        }
        if (appSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return MaterialApp(
            title: 'Test',
            home: StreamBuilder(
              stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
              builder: (context, userSnapshot) {
                if (userSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
                if (userSnapshot.hasData) {
                  print(userSnapshot.data.uid);
                  DocumentReference documentReference = FirebaseFirestore
                      .instance
                      .collection('users')
                      .doc(userSnapshot.data.uid);
                  String userType;
                  documentReference.get().then((snapshot) {
                    Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data();
                    userType = data['type'];
                  });
                  print(userType); //always return null
                  if (userType == 'customer') {
                    return CustomerHomePage();
                  } else {
                    return VendorHomePage();
                  }
                }
                return LoginPage();
              },
            ),
            routes: {
              FoodDetailScreen.routeName: (ctx) => FoodDetailScreen(),
              VendorHomePage.routeName: (ctx) => VendorHomePage(),
              CustomerHomePage.routeName: (ctx) => CustomerHomePage(),
              LoginPage.routeName: (ctx) => LoginPage(),
            },
          );
        }
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) to get the user doc.

```
FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
  future: documentReference.get(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
...
}
```

Comment: But at the same time I also want to listen to FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(), is there a way to listen to the changes and retrieve the user info at the same time